# what's the best method to handle async iterators and await?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, iterator

I know that iterators aren't really handled `async` with node and typescript, but the syntax sugar would seem to lie to me.
If I use a construct like this:

```js
async function(checks) {
    log('start loop')
    checks.forEach(async (check) => {
        actionResult = await this.runAction(check)
        console.log('found 1 actionResult', actionResult)
      }
    })
    log('end loop')
}
```

I would expect the `async` to apply to each inner iteration and wait on the loop to complete.

However the log output begs to differ:

```
    start loop
    end loop
    found 1 actionResult {
```

So the inner event happens "after" the loop has run.
Is this correct/expected behavior? It seems a bit misleading.

I've seen some other syntax like:

`Promise.all( elem => return someAsyncFn(x) )`

which is another way to do it, but a bit hard to read.

`for (const check of checks) {`

A good old `for (const elem of list)` seems to properly observe the async of its outer wrapper, which is the way I usually end up going.

I also just found [for...await of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

So...

- wondering if I have the syntax wrong in the first example? seems like it should work.
- what is the most recommended way in 2020 to do this?
- do generators or other techniques help?

related:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#async-iterators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what's the best method to handle asynchronous operations in an iterator with `await`?

None of the typical array iterations methods such as `.forEach()` and `.map()` are promise-aware.  `.map()` can be used to collect an array of promises that you then `await` with `Promise.all()`, but that runs everything in parallel, not sequentially (useful sometimes, but it appears to not be what you were asking to do).

If you want to run the operations sequentially, then use a regular `for` loop instead of `.forEach()` since `for` will wait for your `await` and will properly sequence your asynchronous operations.  This is the built-in, modern way to do it.

```
async function(checks) {
    log('start loop')
    for (let check of checks) {
        actionResult = await this.runAction(check)
        console.log('found 1 actionResult', actionResult)
    }
    log('end loop')
}
```

`for await (loop parameters here)` is when you have an actual asynchronous iterator which is not what you have here.  Your situation is a regular iterator with an asynchronous operation inside it.

> wondering if I have the syntax wrong in the first example? seems like it should work.

Your `async` callback you pass to `.forEach()` returns a promise, but `.forEach()` doesn't pay any attention to it.  It just blindly goes right onto the next iteration of the loop (even though the asynchronous operations in the first iteration haven't finished yet).  So, that's why it doesn't properly sequence things.  `.forEach()` is not promise-aware.  In fact, it finishes starting every single iteration of the loop before any of the asynchronous operations inside the loop have a chance to finish.

> what is the most recommended way in 2020 to do this?

A regular `for` loop is the modern way to use `await` in a loop when you want the loop iterations to wait for the asynchronous operations before proceeding.

> do generators or other techniques help?

Sometimes in some circumstances, but not needed here.

Comment: thorough answer, thanks! somehow `for...of` just doesn't seem that current anymore!

Comment: @dcsan - `for` and `while` are blessed with support for `await` so those are your best choices.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `forEach` with promises as it's not promise aware

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach does not wait for promises. Kindly make sure you are aware of the implications while using promises(or async functions) as forEach callback.

Answer (score 1):

The `Promise.all` approach is able to process the tasks in parallel (e.g. multiple network requests), while a loop is sequential. It might look uglier, but it can be beneficial for some tasks.

```
async function(checks) {
    log('start loop');
    await Promise.all(
        checks.map((check) => this.runAction(check))
    );
    log('end loop');
}
```

Comment: parallel could be very useful actually for IO tasks or things that ping a DB